# Spring Example HTTP Polling with Apache Kafka Request/Reply

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I was asked this question out of band and thought I would post it here to help the community if similar requirements exist.

Paraphrasing:

I would like to poll an HTTP endpoint for a request/reply scenario, where the controller makes a request over Apache Kafka to a service that returns a reply, but I don't want to block in the controller waiting for the reply; I wish to poll the endpoint periodically to get the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` and the `CompletableFuture` it returns to asynchronously receive the reply and store it for use on the next HTTP poll:

(Note that 3.0.x and above use `CompletableFuture`, 2.9.x returned a `ListenableFuture`, but similar semantics apply there).

For simplicity, this example includes the server code (`@KafkaListener`) too.

Note that the client must provide a unique token of some sort to correlate the request/reply.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> rkt(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf,
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory,
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {

        factory.setReplyTemplate(template);
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = factory.createContainer("replies");
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("replies");
        ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replier = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);
        replier.setDefaultTopic("requests");
        return replier;
    }

    @Bean
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> template(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("requests").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic reply() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("replies").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "upperCaser", topics = "requests")
    @SendTo
    String upperCaseIt(String in) {
        System.out.println("Request: " + in);
        return in.toUpperCase();
    }

}

@RestController
class Controller {

    private final ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> template;

    private final ConcurrentMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private final Set<String> awaiting = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    public Controller(ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/get/foo/{correlation}/{data}")
    public String get(@PathVariable String correlation, @PathVariable String data) {
        if (this.awaiting.add(correlation)) {
            RequestReplyMessageFuture<String, String> future =
                    this.template.sendAndReceive(MessageBuilder.withPayload(data)
                            .build());
            future.whenComplete((msg, ex) -> {
                if (ex == null) {
                    this.map.put(correlation, (String) msg.getPayload());
                }
                else {
                    this.map.put(correlation, "Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
        String reply = this.map.remove(correlation);
        if (reply != null) {
            this.awaiting.remove(correlation);
            return reply + "\n";
        }
        else {
            return "no result yet\n";
        }
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

Result:

```
% curl http://localhost:8080/get/foo/1/test
no result yet
% curl http://localhost:8080/get/foo/1/test
TEST
```